# Is there a way to traverse through a dask dataframe backwards?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

I want to `read_parquet` but read backwards from where you start (assuming a sorted index). I don't want to read the entire parquet into memory because that defeats the whole point of using it. Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the dataframe is indexed, the inversion of the index can be done as a two step process: invert the order of partitions and invert the index within each partition:

```py
from dask.datasets import timeseries

ddf = timeseries()

ddf_inverted = (
    ddf
    .partitions[::-1]
    .map_partitions(lambda df: df.sort_index(ascending=False))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the last N rows are all in the last partition, you can use [`dask.dataframe.tail`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.tail.html). If not, you can iterate backwards using the [`dask.dataframe.partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.partitions.html) attribute. This isn't particularly smart and will blow up your memory if you request too many rows, but it should do the trick:

```py
def get_last_n(n, df):
    read = []
    lines_read = 0
    for i in range(df.npartitions - 1, -1, -1):
        p = df.partitions[i].tail(n - lines_read)

        read.insert(0, p)
        lines_read += len(p)
        if lines_read >= n:
            break

    return pd.concat(read, axis=0)
```

For example, here's a dataframe with 20 rows and 5 partitions:

```py
import dask.dataframe, pandas as pd, numpy as np, dask

df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(20)}), npartitions=5)
```

You can call the above function with any number of rows to get that many rows in the tail:

```py
In [4]: get_last_n(4, df)
Out[4]:
     A
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19

In [5]: get_last_n(10, df)
Out[5]:
     A
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
```

Requesting more rows than are in the dataframe just computes the whole dataframe:

```py
In [6]: get_last_n(1000, df)
Out[6]:
     A
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
```

Note that this requests the data iteratively, so may be very inefficient if your graph is complex and involves lots of shuffles.